# What is the best method to detect xml in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, mime-types

What is the best method to detect xml in JavaScript

e.g. is it possible to detect the mime type of a document - particularly if it is text/xml in JavaScript.

this needs to work in Chrome.

thanks,

Josh

Comment: In what context? Are you fetching things with AJAX and need to determine what kind of document you're fetching?

Comment: what to transform a document with xslt but need to know its xml before i try.

Comment: Where does the document you want to transform come from? There are many possible answers to your question but only one of them will be correct, and which one it is depends on knowing where the document is from (and indeed if it's a document at all - for example, a string containing a serialisation of an XML document is _not_ a document).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `XMLHttpRequest` to get this data, then you can simply check for the `Content-Type` header using the `getResponseHeader` method (granted that the server sends the appropriate headers).

```
var getFile = function(address, responseHandler) {
  var req = new XMLHttpRequest();  

  req.open('get', address, true);  
  req.onreadystatechange = responseHandler;
  req.send(null);  
}

var responseHandler = function(resp) {
  if ( this.readyState < 4 ) { return; }
  console.log(this.getResponseHeader("Content-Type"));
};

getFile("http://zebrakick.com/some/file", responseHandler);
```

(I seem to be using this code sample a lot...)

Answer (score 0):

You can't determine what the mime-type is with Javascript. I would recommend doing checks on the data returned to see if it is valid XML before you try to parse it. (I'm only assuming what you're trying to do. I can provide a more rigid example if you clarify what your goal is.)

Answer (score 0):

I came across this when looking to determine that a chrome extension script was on an XML page.  Maybe this saves someone a few minutes.

In the chrome console and content scripts you can check with:

```
document.contentType==="application/xml"
```